# lower_bound and upper_bound for after and before

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I would like to search in an event database and check what is the immediate event before time `t` and what is the immediate event after time `t`. If the event happens exactly at time `t`, I would like the both before and after be equal to each other. If the given time is before or after all database events, then the most extreme event must be given for both before and after. Here is the code:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 test2.cpp -Wfatal-errors

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Event
{
    double event_time;
    std::string info;

};

bool operator< (const Event &e1,double rhs_time)
{
    return e1.event_time<rhs_time;
}
bool operator< (double lhs_time,const Event &e2)
{
    return lhs_time<e2.event_time;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<Event> events=
    {
        {0.0, "Player 1 built a village"},
        {2.0, "Player 2 relocated"},
        {2.5, "Player 2 attacked plyer 3"},
        {4.0, "Player 4 built walls"},
        {6.0, "Player 3 left the game"},
        {7.0, "Player 2 built a village"},
    };
    std::vector<Event>::iterator before,after;
    double search_time=4.5;
    before=std::lower_bound (events.begin(), events.end(), search_time);
    after= std::upper_bound (events.begin(), events.end(), search_time);
    std::cout<<"What happened before and after "<<search_time<<"?"<<std::endl;
    std::cout
            <<"before: @"<<(before->event_time)
            <<", "<<(before->info)<<std::endl;
    std::cout
            <<"after: @"<<(after->event_time)
            <<", "<<(after->info)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the result is

```
What happened before and after 4.5?
before: @6, Player 3 left the game
after: @6, Player 3 left the game
```

While I was expecting:

```
What happened before and after 4.5?
before: @4, Player 4 built walls
after: @6, Player 3 left the game
```

The vector is sorted.

How should I fix this code?

([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jKzYp7S8XYcruvXm))

Comment: Be careful when using floating point numbers as indexes, you can get into trouble with floating point inaccuracies. The example you posted here with every number ending in .0 or .5 won't have that problem, but it's easy for that to change.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Thanks for mentioning this point. I am totally aware of that. This is a MWE. In practice, I will use a data structure instead of a text info and I use interpolation. Hence, I am not much worried about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lower_bound` will return the first element that is greater than or equal to the search item. In this case that is element 6.0.

`upper_bound` will return the first element that is greater but *not* equal to the search item. In this case that is also element 6.0.

To get the element before the number you're searching for, you need to explicitly decrement the iterator returned from `lower_bound`. To prevent undefined behavior you will first need to make sure it isn't already at `begin()`.

Think of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` as returning the *range* of where that item would be placed in the sorted array. If the search item doesn't occur in the sequence, they will always return the same iterator.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed the [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yLyEEfDWjqLCAuXS). Does this code guarantee that on a sorted database always `after=before` or `after=before+1`?

Comment: @ar2015 it does if there are no duplicates in the sequence. Otherwise you get `after=before+n` where `n` is the number of duplicates.